# Intellij and Visual Studio emulator for Android log generation issue

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

I am using the Intellij idea with Visual Studio emulator for Android given the great look and feel and ease of that emulator but I am not able to see the logs in the ide using the log.d() method.

The code is here:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d("android ", "onStart: ");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("andorid", "onStop: ");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("", "onDestroy: ");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("", "onResume: ");
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d("", "onRestart: ");
}
```

and though all other methods like that are being called and function properly yet only the log is not being shown. I believe there's a problem of communication between the emulator and ide since the emulator is not native.

Comment: Can you connect to the emulator using `adb`? Does `adb logcat` show the log?

Comment: Well when I run the project the ide prompts me to choose the emulator i want to use which is where i choose vs emulator for android. I am not aware of the adb way of running it. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: I mean the command line `adb` tool from Android SDK that you can use to verify if you can connect to the emulator and see the logs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I tried to connect but it gave an error saying connection failed.

Comment: You need to resolve this issue somehow, the problem is not IDE specific here.

Comment: I got this answer from a similar thread "Do you see any error message in the beginning regarding ADB? Considering that it is working on cordova, try rebooting once to make sure there is no one-off problems. If that doesn't work, you can manually connect adb using

adb connect <ip>:5555"
can u understand where to add this command?